# set-alias to executable plus command-line option

Tags: powershell

In PowerShell, `& "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1\bin\jjs.exe" --language=es6` gives me access to the Nashorn interpreter for ES6.  I want to create an alias for exactly this.  How can I create an alias to start this process with the desired command-line option?

Comment: Aliases don't support that. Define a function instead: `function nashorn { & "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1\bin\jjs.exe" --language=es6 }`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks; I was aware of this solution.  Can you say simply why this is beyond the scope of aliases?  (I'm pretty new to PowerShell.) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Putting Mathias's comment as an answer. You should create it as a function and finally you can call the function wherever you need it just by the name.

```
function call-nashorn 
{ 
    & "C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1\bin\jjs.exe" --language=es6 
}
call-nashorn
```